# A small pond-crossing

Tags: story, river-crossing

While walking through the flower gardens, you encounter a small group of fairies stuck on a lilypad. There are 2 red fairies, 2 yellow fairies, and 2 green fairies, and they have nothing besides a floating leaf to use as a raft. They explain that they're trapped on the lilypad, as the leaf can only hold 2 fairies at a time, and must always have at least 1 fairy to be operated. Furthermore, the green fairies fear being eaten by the yellow fairies if they're outnumbered, and the yellows have a similar fear of the reds

What is the lowest number of moves required to get them from the lilypad onto dry land?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the restrictions, the minimum possible number of moves is nine. Five trips with two fairies from lilypad to land, and four trips back with a single fairy to return the leaf, to get all six fairies on dry land.

The minimum that can be achieved with the restrictions is:

> Still nine.
>  1. RY to dry land
>  2. Y back to the lilypad
>  3. GG to dry land
>  4. R back to the lilypad
>  5. RR to dry land
>  6. R back to the lilypad
>  7. YY to dry land
>  8. R back to the lilypad
>  9. RR to dry land

Answer (score 0):

Firstly note that the leaf should be occupied by 2 fairies (outgoing) or 1 fairy (incoming) every time, so there's never any outnumbering on the leaf. We just need to make sure no outnumbering happens on dry land or on the lilypad.

1. > Move one red and one yellow fairy. On the lilypad: **1 red, 1 yellow, 2 green**. On dry land: **1 red, 1 yellow**. Nobody is outnumbering anyone, except the green fairies whom nobody fears.
2. > One yellow fairy goes back, and two green fairies return. On the lilypad: briefly **1 red, 2 yellow, 2 green**, then **1 red, 2 yellow**. On dry land: briefly **1 red**, then **1 red, 2 green**.
3. > One red fairy goes back, and two red fairies return. On the lilypad: briefly **2 red, 2 yellow**, then **2 yellow**. On dry land: briefly **2 green**, then **2 red, 2 green**.
4. > One red fairy goes back, and two yellow fairies return. On the lilypad: briefly **1 red, 2 yellow**, then **1 red**. On dry land: briefly **1 red, 2 green**, then **1 red, 2 yellow, 2 green**. Reds don't fear being outnumbered.
5. > One red fairy goes back, and two red fairies return. The lilypad is all red, no outnumbering. On dry land: briefly **2 yellow, 2 green**, then **2 red, 2 yellow, 2 green** and they all continue happily on together.

Comment: I should have mentioned this from the start, but the raft can't be moved back without a fairy in it

Answer (score 0):

The following works and is minimal in terms of number of trips (although there are other possible options):

> RG-out/R-back; YY-out/Y-back; RY-out/R-back; RR-out/G-back; GG-out

Comment: After the first move, the yellows would outnumber the green fairy